# Call function when clicking on a SVG element in Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I have an angular 4 application with an SVG image.
I want to call a function when clicking on an part of the SVG.

This is how I display my svg :

```
 <div class="svg" [innerHtml]="mySVG"> </div>
```

with `this.mySVG = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(containerSVGString);` where `containerSVGString` is the string of the content of the SVG.

So, if in the SVG I have something like : `<g id="all" onclick="console.log('test')">` it works.

But if I try to do `<g id="all" onclick="myFunction()">` with

```
myFunction(){
    console.log('test);
}
```

declared in my typescript file, it doesn't work.

Do you know how I can do to call one of my functions when clicking on a SVG element ?

**EDIT :**
I get this error :

```
monitoring:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
at SVGGElement.onclick
```

Comment: If you are using Angular, why do you try to add `onclick` property? May be you need to use angular notation like `(click)="myFunction()"`

Comment: I tried to do it with `(click)="myFunction()"` but it the same. It  doesn't work.

Comment: @MysterX He shouldn't use `(click)` if he places code by using innerHTML

Comment: There are different solutions for this

Comment: would you mind setting up a plunkr?

Comment: @yurzui Could you give one solution ?

Comment: I can't create a plunkr. The SVG file is not read...

Comment: Example 1 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbjxi2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Example 2 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnokgj?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui Thanks ! But could you explain what you do ?

Comment: Example 3 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbrdez?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui Thanks a lot ! I didn't understand the first example... The second example can't work for me because the click is not on the all SVG but just on an element. So I tried the third example but it doesn't work. I have this error : ` Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. Do you know why ?

Comment: In first example i just expose component function to window object therefore onclick will find it. Second example shows event delegation. It can be any element. The third example is traversing, you should know the exact selector

Comment: In the third example target is null for me. Do you know why ?

Comment: Create example and i will know why)

Comment: Ok, methods 1 and 2 works !! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example code,clicking on download svg icon,component method downloadFile will be called.

**Html** : Assuming there is a icon of download in asset folder also make sure to add pointer-events: none which makes sure that click event is triggered.

```
 <div class="icon-placeholder" (click)="downloadFile()">
          <object data="../../../assets/images/icon-download.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
            style="pointer-events: none;"></object>
          <span>Download</span>
        </div>
```

**CSS**  : adding css

```
 .icon-placeholder {      
      font-size: 12px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      cursor: pointer !important ;
    }
```

**ts** file:

```
downloadFile(){
console.log('svg clicked');
}
```

Comment: some code improvements: Don't use (click) on a div, use a button for this. Also no need to use object for displaying svg, use a normal image tag.

Answer (score 0):

declare downloadFile() function in js, or in <script> tag in index.html

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Please elaborate this answer with the **edit** option, to make it clearer how your answer solves the issue. Please read: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)